# Why process noise model is$ \dfrac{T^4}{4}$ in Kalman filter.

Tags: matrices, signal-processing, bayesian-network, noise, kalman-filter

I am using Kalman filter for filtering noise on 2D object movement. I read a lot of examples, but no one has been explained, why noise model is distance powered by 2:

$$
s \times s = \dfrac{T^2}{2} \times \dfrac{T^2}{2} = \dfrac{T^4}{4};
$$

My process noise model is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 T^4/4 & 0  &    T^3/2 & 0      \\ 
 0     & T^4/4 &  0    & T^3/2  \\ 
 T^3/2 & 0     & T^2     &0      \\ 
 0     & T^3/2 & 0     &T^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My state model is standard:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 x & y & \dot{x} & \dot{y} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You get that process noise matrix if you discretize

$\dot{x} = w_1(t)$

$\dot{y} = w_2(t)$

where $w$ are white noise signals. The Wikipedia "Kalman Filter" page derives an example with a vehicle that is very similar.